# mysql limit not working multiple record against 1 id

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, limit

Mysql procedure gives three records against 1 id. I am trying to get only 1 record against 1 id. where to put a limit to access only 1 record against 1 id

Create DEFINER=`xxxx`@`xxxx.%` PROCEDURE `xxxx`(

```
    IN pCompanyId BIGINT(20)
        )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
         `zp`.`PlaceId`,
         `zp`.`PlaceName`,
         `zp`.`PlaceCategoryCode`,
         `zp`.`Description`,
         `zp`.`CompanyId_FK`,
         `zp`.`OwnerCompanyId_FK`,
         `zp`.`IsDeleted`,
         `zp`.`IsArchived`,
         `zp`.`CreatedDate`,
         `zp`.`ModifiedDate`,
         `zp`.`CreatedBy_FK`,
         `zp`.`ModifiedBy_FK`,
         (SELECT COUNT(`ApplianceId`) FROM `ZThinQ_Appliance` WHERE `ApplianceActionCode` = 1 AND `PlaceId_FK` = `PlaceId`)  AS activeDevices ,
         (SELECT COUNT(`ApplianceId`) FROM `ZThinQ_Appliance` where  `PlaceId_FK` = `PlaceId` ) AS totalDevices

        FROM `ZThinQ_Place` AS `zp` 
        JOIN `ZThinQ_Appliance` as `za`

        #ON `ZThinQ_Appliance`
        #ON `PlaceId` = `PlaceId_FK` 

        Where `zp`.`CompanyId_FK`=pCompanyId;


    END
```

Comment: You could improve this question by adding table definitions, sample date and expected outcome as text to the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a rows  you could add  limit 1 to yoru query

```
 SELECT 
     `zp`.`PlaceId`,
     `zp`.`PlaceName`,
     `zp`.`PlaceCategoryCode`,
     `zp`.`Description`,
     `zp`.`CompanyId_FK`,
     `zp`.`OwnerCompanyId_FK`,
     `zp`.`IsDeleted`,
     `zp`.`IsArchived`,
     `zp`.`CreatedDate`,
     `zp`.`ModifiedDate`,
     `zp`.`CreatedBy_FK`,
     `zp`.`ModifiedBy_FK`,
     (SELECT COUNT(`ApplianceId`) FROM `ZThinQ_Appliance` WHERE `ApplianceActionCode` = 1 AND `PlaceId_FK` = `PlaceId`)  AS activeDevices ,
     (SELECT COUNT(`ApplianceId`) FROM `ZThinQ_Appliance` where  `PlaceId_FK` = `PlaceId` ) AS totalDevices

    FROM `ZThinQ_Place` AS `zp` 
    JOIN `ZThinQ_Appliance` as `za`

    #ON `ZThinQ_Appliance`
    #ON `PlaceId` = `PlaceId_FK` 

    Where `zp`.`CompanyId_FK`=pCompanyId
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your are right but i need `PlaceId` 's one record  which are 3 in reponse @scaisEdge

Comment: @LODE  I don't understand  ..  please explain better  .. try update your question adding a proper data sample, your actual result  and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple records against 1 id. So i use select distinct in my procedure .that's it

```
SELECT distinct
 `zp`.`PlaceId`,
 `zp`.`PlaceName`,
 `zp`.`PlaceCategoryCode`,
 `zp`.`Description`,
 `zp`.`CompanyId_FK`,
 `zp`.`OwnerCompanyId_FK`,
 `zp`.`IsDeleted`,
 `zp`.`IsArchived`,
 `zp`.`CreatedDate`,
 `zp`.`ModifiedDate`,
 `zp`.`CreatedBy_FK`,
 `zp`.`ModifiedBy_FK`,
 (SELECT COUNT(`ApplianceId`) FROM `ZThinQ_Appliance` WHERE `ApplianceActionCode` = 1 AND `PlaceId_FK` = `PlaceId`)  AS activeDevices ,
 (SELECT COUNT(`ApplianceId`) FROM `ZThinQ_Appliance` where  `PlaceId_FK` = `PlaceId` ) AS totalDevices

FROM `ZThinQ_Place` AS `zp` 
JOIN `ZThinQ_Appliance` as `za`

#ON `ZThinQ_Appliance`
#ON `PlaceId` = `PlaceId_FK` 

Where `zp`.`CompanyId_FK`=pCompanyId
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @scaisEdge please review and accept may helpful for other